# Django. Get data from post json request and search

Tags: python, json, django, post, get

I have my models

FormField:

```
class FormField(models.Model):
    fieldName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = 'text'
    email = 'example@email.mail'
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    date = models.DateTimeField
    TYPE_OF_FIELD_CHOICE = (
        (text, 'text'),
        (email, 'example@email.mail'),
        (phone, '+9123456789'),
        (date, '2017-01-01')
    )
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=25,
                                   choices=TYPE_OF_FIELD_CHOICE,
                                   default=text)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.fieldName
```

FormPattern

```
class FormPattern(models.Model):
    formName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(FormField)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.formName
```

And i need get data from json request and search it in FormField
For example : mysite/get_data?f_name1=value1&f_name2=value2

If i found form with fields like this i need to send response in json with name of form's pattern.

How can i handle this. I read something about json_view but dont find anything about get data from post json request. Please help if you can.

Comment: I'm not able to make sense of your question and what you are trying to do here. But if you make a GET request to `mysite/get_data?f_name1=value1&f_name2=value2`, the payload is in the url parameters. There's no json payload needed. You can access the parameters in you view code from the `request.GET` QueryDict object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Comment: Thank you. Due your comment i found information about rest django framework and solve my problem